# How to specify conditional multiple xelements in XDocument creation?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

```
new XDocument(
    new XElement("first",
       condition==true?
       new XElement("second","2nd"),
       new XElement("third","3rd"):null
    )
)
```

The syntax above is probably not right but what I wish to achieve is how to wrap the inclusion of multiple xelements in one condition.

Comment: Please post a question and format appropriately.

Comment: Done. Please look again

Comment: I assume you should be using an if, `if (condition == true) { /* add "second", "third" here */ } else { /* add null here */ }

Comment: It looks like you want to know how to use the Ternary Operator

Comment: Can you give examples of the output you'd like to see if the condition is true and if it's false (in XML form)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a list expression  like that in a conditional statement. The comma in there is from a parameter list, and both branches of the `?:` have to be assignment compatible.

It should look something like below:

```
new XDocument(
    new XElement("first",
       condition==true
        ? new XElement[] {new XElement("second","2nd"),
                         new XElement("third","3rd") }
        : null //new XElement[] { }
    )
)
```

Edit: the else-branch can just use `null`